# Is there a way to find the invaded player?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know there's a miracle that is used to find the invader, but as the invader, does that miracle work or is there any other way to find the player?

This is because I get frustrated in places like the Dragon Shrine where players escape to Dragon Aerie and sometimes I am simply unable to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to find an invaded player or an invader is to use the miracle: [Unveil](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Unveil#.U208Sfl_uZw)
If you're the invader, Unveil will work to help you find the invaded player.

Be wary that Unveil will often point you to a random enemy and not necessarily to a human player.

Unfortunately, there's no other (easy) way to find your enemies.

Comment: Please take another look at the question since you're refering to the invader, not the invaded player.

Comment: I wrote my answer wrong but did not read the question wrong. The answer stays the same, there's no other way than Unveil. Editted.

Comment: Please edit again the question so that I can remove the -1, it says you need to edit it before I can do it.